Styling Avalonia Slider Conntrol
I would like to style the sizes and colors of Avalonia Slider Control.
Visually it seems to work but it stops the sliding functionailty, I tried to look at the Slider source code to find out how to do it properly but cannot figure it out. Here is the code that I am using:
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Slider Width="200" Height="100" Margin="10" Minimum="120" Maximum="255" Value="210">
        <Slider.Styles>
            <Style Selector="Slider:horizontal">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="40" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" Height="6" Margin="6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Background="Orange" />
                            <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Thumb Name="thumb" MinWidth="20" MinHeight="20">
                                    <Thumb.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Ellipse Width="18" Height="18" StrokeThickness="3"
                                                     Stroke="Crimson" Fill="Green" />
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Thumb.Template>
                                </Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Slider.Styles>
    </Slider>
</Border>


It seems to look as expected but it does not slide. Even the initial value is not set.

The problem you are having is you've overridden the template but not included all the template components, so things are now missing. You shouldn't set a control template just to change the Style. Avalonia has a robust "drill down" selector system that allows you to style anything in the template by inheriting the parent selector using the ^.  By preceding your Selector with that symbol you can nest styles.
<Style Selector="Slider:horizontal">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>

    <Style Selector="^ Track">
        <Style Selector="^ RepeatButton Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="6"/>
        </Style>
                        
        <Style Selector="^ Thumb">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </Style>

</Style>

On the above I did not style the :hover pseudoclass, but I think this should get you the information you need to do it.
The track of the slider is actually a RepeatButton, this lets you click it to make it function.  There are two of them, one on either side of the Thumb, so if you want different styles on either side you will have to select them independently by their names (PART_IncreaseButton and PART_DecreaseButton) for example ^ RepeatButton#PART_DecreaseButton Border.

I found at some point the drill down command ^ but did not know the difference with the "older" way of doing it. Anyway, by using your example and adding styles for ^ RepeatButton#PART_DecreaseButton and ^ RepeatButton#PART_IncreaseButton I achieved what I needed. Thanks for the help!

BTW, is it possible to set a gradient for the horizontal line, so that when I move the slider the gradient will stay the same from left to right, without splitting the Decrease and Increase buttons? In other words, I want to have the horizontal line with the static brush, and not separate ones for the Increase and Decrease buttons.

You could split the gradient.  For example, if you have Red to Green to Blue you could have Red to Green on one button and Green to Blue on the other button.  You just have to find the midpoint of whatever gradient you are using.  But that's still going to change a little because the buttons are resized as the thumb moves.

Also, just to clarify, the ^ is not actually a drill down command, it just inherits the parent selector.  In this context the following are identical.  ^ RepeatButton Border and Slider:horizontal Track RepeatButton Border. But the first one is just cleaner and easier to read.

Thanks for the suggestion. I tried splitting but decided to cheat instead added a border with the gradient behind the slider and set Background to transparent on ^ RepeatButton Border, ^ RepeatButton#PART_DecreaseButton, and ^ RepeatButton#PART_DecreaseButton. It looks like it is working so far.

That, sort-of, would have been my next suggestion.  I was going to say you could also go ahead and re-template the Track (not the slider) with a border like that.  Glad you got it where you like it though.

I tried looking at Track and could not find either Background or Panel to put the Border with the gradient. So if you could give me a hint on how to do it, that would be great.

You would have to re-template it to add the border, like you tried to do with Slider originally.  But when you supply a new template, you replace the old one, so you have to make sure you have all the required components (PART_xxxxx) for the control to function.

I see. Thanks. Maybe one day I will try to redefine the Slider template to make it work.
